# Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected token.\nclient_id=xxxx\n^ error when use authCode to exchange access and refresh token

Tags: curl, google-api, google-oauth

I'm used vue-google-oauth2 to get authCode from google, then I want to use it to exchange access and refresh token by below:

```
curl -d "client_id=0123456789012-xxxxxxxxxxx..apps.googleusercontent.com&\
  client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET&\
  redirect_uri=postmessage&\
  grant_type=authorization_code&\
  code=MY_AUTH_CODE" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --header 'Accept: application/json' https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

but I get an 400 error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected token.\nclient_id=012345678\n^",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

What I went wrong? Thanks for your support

**To Reproduce**

Replace client_id, client_secret, auth_code and run above Curl command

**Expected behavior**

Google OAuth response access token and refresh token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the returns you have \n in the string those /n's are confusing it.

```
# Client id from Google Developer console
# Client Secret from Google Developer console
# Scope this is a space seprated list of the scopes of access you are requesting.

# Authorization link.  Place this in a browser and copy the code that is returned after you accept the scopes.
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=[Application Client Id]&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=[Scopes]&response_type=code

# Exchange Authorization code for an access token and a refresh token.

curl \
--request POST \
--data "code=[Authentcation code from authorization link]&client_id=[Application Client Id]&client_secret=[Application Client Secret]&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code" \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

# Exchange a refresh token for a new access token.
curl \
--request POST \
--data 'client_id=[Application Client Id]&client_secret=[Application Client Secret]&refresh_token=[Refresh token granted by second step]&grant_type=refresh_token' \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

code from my curl example [GoogleAuthenticationCurl.sh](https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/cff75182aac5fa42930a09f58b63a309)